# Is thre an any function in ModSecurity to set relevant parameters regular expression like SecAuditLogRelevantStatus option?

Tags: apache

I'm using ModSecuity with my Apache server, and I want to set it to not log requets who has a determineted parameter in querystring.

In mod_secuirty.conf, I have this following configs:

```
SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
SecAuditLogRelevantStatus "^(?:5|4(?!04))"
```

And I want to set somethint like SecAuditLogRelevantParameter "?!(test)" (to log any request who doen't have the **test** parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mod_security2** for Apache [supports](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#ctl) the `ctl:auditLogParts` and `ctl:auditLogEngine` (note: libmodsecurity3 does not support `auditLogEngine` sub-action for `ctl`). Thus you can make a rule, that turns off the audit engine, or modify the log parts. I think you want to turn it off, so based on your request you need something like this:

```
SecAction
  "id:111001,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:tx.args_contains_test=0"

SecRule ARGS_NAMES "@rx test" \
    "id:111002,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    t:lowercase,
    setvar:'tx.args_contains_test=1'"

SecRule TX:args_contains_tests "@lt 1" 
    "id:111003,\
    phase:2,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:auditLogEngine=Off"
```

Put these rules to the very beginning of your rule set - if you use CRS, then the `REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf` is a good choice.

**How this exclusion works?**

As you wrote above, the condition is *"any request who **dosen't** have the test parameter"*. This is not so trivial, because you have to check that **something is not exists**, therefore you have to inspect all arguments.

In ModSecurity, you can do it only whit this way above: first, you have to set up a transaction variable, which stores the information, the request contains any argument with name `test` or not. That's the first (and only) `SecAction`.

`@rx test` is a ModSecurity operator and its argument, that checks the `ARGS_NAMES` collection. This collection contains all of the request's arguments. The rule `111002` checks all argument names, and if there are any variable with name like `test` (regex matches), then it changes the TX variable.

The rule `111003` checks the TX variable, and if it's 1, then disables the auditLog engine for the **current** transaction. That's it.

Please note, that the `@rx` operator is [case-sensitive](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#rx), that's why the `t:lowercase` is there.

Also note, that the two `SecRule`s executed in `phase:2`. If you want to check the GET parameter, then you have to move this rule to `phase:1`. If you want to check all possible variables, then you have to duplicate this rule: one for the `phase:1` and the other one for `phase:2` - with a unique id!

If you want to turn off the auditLogEngine with a QUERY_STRING parameter, eg. `http://example.com/form.cgi?test=1`, then the solution is more simple - but anyone can turn off at this way:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@endsWith test=1" \
    "id:111001,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    t:lowercase,\
    ctl:auditLogEngine=Off"
```